# Ruby - Watir gem to grab links

Tags: ruby, watir, ruby-1.9

Is there any way to get all the links given an attribute?

Down the tree, I get a lot of these tags:

```
<div class="name">
<a hef="http://www.example.com/link">This is a name</a>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do something like this: `b.links(:class, "name")` and it'll output all the hyperlinks and titles from all div name classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly how you've described the browser objects regarding  attributes, this is how you'd have to do that.  Otherwise, @SporkInventor's answer is spot on for link attributes.

```
@myLinks = Array.new
@browser.divs(:class => "name").each do |d|  
   d.links.each {|link| @myLinks << link }
end
```

1. Create a new array to collect our links.
2. For every div in the browser with class that equals "name", grab all the links and throw them into the array.

   @myLinks.each {|link| puts link.href } #etc, etc

Comment: All solutions are great actually. Wish I could give everyone points. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a css selector in this case:

```
#If you want all links anywhere within the div with class "name"
browser.links(:css => 'div.name a')

#If you want all links that are a direct child of the div with class "name"
browser.links(:css => 'div.name > a')
```

or if you prefer xpath:

```
#If you want all links anywhere within the div with class "name"
browser.links(:xpath => '//div[@class="name"]//a')

#If you want all links that are a direct child of the div with class "name"
browser.links(:xpath => '//div[@class="name"]/a')
```

**Example (css)**

Assume you have an HTML like:

```
<div class="name">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/link1">
        This link is a direct child of the div
    </a>
</div>
<div class="stuff">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/link2">
        This link does not have the matching div
    </a>
</div>
<div class="name">
    <span>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/link3">
            This link is not a direct child of the div
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then the css methods would give the results:

```
browser.links(:css, 'div.name a').collect(&:href)
#=> ["http://www.example.com/link1", "http://www.example.com/link3"]

browser.links(:css, 'div.name > a').collect(&:href)
#=> ["http://www.example.com/link1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done with out-of-the box watir.

However it can be done, exactly as you have types, using 'waitr-webdriver'.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x59c0fcd6 url="about:blank" title="">
irb(main):003:0> b.goto "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
=> "http://stackoverflow.com/"
irb(main):004:0> b.links.length
=> 770
irb(main):005:0> b.links(:class, 'question-hyperlink').length
=> 91
```